# Accessing element in array with assembly

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

Assume the following function:

```
void asmFunction(const int *first, ...) {
    __asm {
        xor eax, eax
        add eax, [first][0]
        ; ...
    }
}
```

It is being called this way:

```
int first[] =  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5 };
asmFunction2(first, ...);
```

As far as I understand, the second assembly line must add `0` element of array `first`  to `eax`. However, a random value is being added. When debugging, `first[0]` equals 0, as it must be. What is the problem with the code?

I code in Visual Studio 2013 on 64-bit machine.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but shouldn't it be `add eax, [first + 0]`? With `[]` you dereference the `first` pointer/address.  And for element 1: `add eax, [first + 4]`, etc.

Comment: @meaning-matters As far as I know, `[first][0]` means the same as `[first + 0]`, but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a strange syntax and probably doesn't do what you want. If you disassemble the generated code you will most likely see something like `add eax, [ebp+8]`. The random value added should be the value of `first`, which is a pointer. You have effectively done `eax += first`. To get at the elements you need a level of indirection, that is `eax += *first`. For example this could work:

```
mov edx, [first]
add eax, [edx]
```

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, currently I’m unable to test it.
Is the `add eax, [[first]]` syntax acceptable or wrong?

Comment: x86 doesn't support double indirection, so even if some assembler accepts that form, it's not going to work either.